# What software is availble to forward a mysql socket file to a remote server?

Tags: mysql, sockets

I used to run a mysql server on a box where clients would connect to localhost (/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock), but have subsequently moved the MySQL server to dedicated hardware.

To date, I have successfully been able to use both socat and mysql-proxy to make /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock forward to the remote server, but I wonder what other options are availble, ideally something that can implement caching would be desirable. I played around with ProxySQL but realised that wasn't for me, as it would need a list of all users.
As mysql-proxy was only ever declared alpha I'd like to use something else.

Comment: Typically one uses sockets only for local connections and TCP for remote.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql

Comment: It seems you want to rule out TCP but you don't say that explicitly. Maybe you should clarify that because for TCP a lot of software is available (stunnel, ssh, MySQL directly, etc.) while for unix socket files not so much.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm in a situation where i have hundreds of clients connecting to local host, and changing all their connection strings would be too difficult. For anyone connecting to 127.0.0.1 or the IP address of the box, I have redirected with iptables